# Expo 41 + @stripe/react-native: cannot find package.json

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I followed the set up [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native) of just doing `npm install @stripe/stripe-react-native`. I installed and then added the provider, but I got this error:

```
Failed to compile.
/home/user/Projects/project/project_frontend/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/lib/module/components/StripeProvider.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../package.json' in '/home/user/Projects/project/project_frontend/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/lib/module/components'
```

I added the provider just like in the docs. No idea why it wont work:

```js
export default function NativeCheckout() {
  return (
    <StripeProvider
      publishableKey={STRIPE.publishableKey}
      merchantIdentifier="merchant.identifier"
    >
      <PaymentScreen />
    </StripeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you add package.json code?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak I will do it once I get home

Comment: If you're testing this in the Expo web view, this is expected: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/291 `stripe-react-native` doesn't support React Native for web at this point.

Comment: @PaulAsjes do you know a way to get around this? I am happy to put in the work if it is possible to support all platforms.

Comment: Currently the only way around it would be to use Stripe Elements in a webview.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=custom

Comment: For anyone else here, you can have two files: checkout.native.js and checkout.web.js and it compiles to either or. That's how to get around cross platform. Use regular stripe checkout elements for web and stripe-react-native for native